# How do I create a C++ or C# project, in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I create a C++ or C# project, in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: You actully had to ask this question on SO? You coulnd't just think to yourself, "Gee, I wonder what File -> New does?". Really!

Comment: @Lucas: C++ and C# components need not be installed together with Visual Studio, therefore it might be confusing to users finding VS on a PC but no option to create C# or C++ projects.

Comment: @divo: I never had any trouble with it as a beginner. I think most people just get lazy and don't look. The way I learned my way around VS was by exploring. When you explore you get a good filling when you find something new. You should have seen my face when I found out how to change the font colors ;-)

Comment: @divo: if this is at all true, it should be mentioned in the question. Such as, "I went to File/New/Project, and expected to see C++ there, but instead it only says Visual Basic and ASP.NET".   As asked, this question is worthless, and the rest of us are left to guess what he actually meant.

Comment: Predictably, the noob got his question answered, but hasn't upvoted good answers, or accepted the best answer.  I think I will no longer answer any questions from noobs.  They drain SO of value when they don't participate.

Answer (score 1):

Click on `File -> New -> Project` and select the type of project you want to create. Then, give it a name. Then click `OK`!

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you have? Does it have C# on the loading screen?

File > New > Choose your C# project type and away you go

Answer (score 0):

To create a c++ project:

File > New > Project > Other Languages > Visual C++ and pick the type you need.

C#

File > New > Project > Visual C# and pick the type you need.

The Express editions are hardwired for C# or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to have selected the C# and C++ components at the time you installed Visual Studio. If you only selected VB, you first need to re-run the setup to add these features.

Answer (score 0):

To find-out what is installed, check the about dialog, Help -> About, this tells you want components are installed. If you have C# or C++ installed, then you can create a new project via the File menu as other have pointed out.

If you have an existing solution, then right click on the solution title in Solution Explorer and Add New project.